# How to find if a special character is present in a string in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to check whether a string contains `#` or not.
Then if it contains `#`, I want to find the content after `#`.

For example,

- `test#1` — This should return me `1`.
- `test*1` — This should not return anything.
- `test#123Test` — This should return `123Test`.

Please let me know. Thanx in advance.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "should not return anything" - if you were to encapsulate this in a method, you'd have to return *something* - do you want an empty string, or null, for example? Or do you want it to throw an exception? You've got a tag of `regex` but is there any reason why you want to use regular expressions for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Compile a regular expression: A hash followed by any number of characters
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("#(.*)");

// Match input data
Matcher m = p.matcher("test#1");

// Check if there is a match
if (m.find()) {

  // Get the first matching group (in parentheses)
  System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd use simple string operations rather than a regular expression:

```
int index = text.indexOf('#');
return index == -1 ? "" : text.substring(index + 1);
```

(I'm assuming "should not return anything" means "return empty string" here - you could change it to return `null` if you want.)